# Two events on a button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

How can I make more than one event on a button?

```
public JButton getNumero1() {
    numero1Button = new JButton();
    numero1Button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ic_images/bt_n1.png")));
    ActionListener monitorador = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

            entradaNumero1.setText(("1"));
            entradaNumero1.setEnabled(false);

            entradaNumero2.setText(("2"));
            entradaNumero2.setEnabled(false);


        }
    };

    numero1Button.addActionListener(monitorador);
    return numero1Button;
}
```

I want to do with the first being a JTextField, and then another!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add any number of action listeners to a button

**Java 7 way**

```
public JButton getNumero1() {
    numero1Button = new JButton();
    numero1Button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ic_images/bt_n1.png")));
    ActionListener monitorador1 = new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          entradaNumero1.setText(("1"));
          entradaNumero1.setEnabled(false);
        }
     };
     numero1Button.addActionListener(monitorador1);
     ActionListener monitorador2 = new ActionListener() {
       public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
          entradaNumero2.setText(("2"));
          entradaNumero2.setEnabled(false);
        }
     };
     numero1Button.addActionListener(monitorador2);
     return numero1Button;
 }
```

**Java 8 way**

```
public JButton getNumero1() {
     numero1Button = new JButton();
     numero1Button.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/ic_images/bt_n1.png")));
     ActionListener monitorador1 = e -> {
        entradaNumero1.setText(("1"));
        entradaNumero1.setEnabled(false);
     };
     numero1Button.addActionListener(monitorador1);
     ActionListener monitorador2 = e -> {
        entradaNumero1.setText(("1"));
        entradaNumero1.setEnabled(false);
     };
     numero1Button.addActionListener(monitorador2);
     return numero1Button;
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

> How can I make more than one event on a button?

Nothing is preventing you as you are allowed to:

- Add more than one ActionListener to a JButton
- Remove ActionListeners
- Swap them (by adding and removing)...
- Have listeners that do more than one thing...

---

Note that this is unclear:

> I want to do with the first being a JTextField, and then another!

Comment: I did not understand. It is to give an example?